# Icons in compiled jar file

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, awt

I use next code to set icons on the buttons

```
private JButton loadTxtButton = new JButton("Load .txt");
private JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
private JButton solveButton = new JButton("Solve");

private SudokuSolverMain() {
    ...
    loadTxtButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/com/tum4ik/icons/upload.png"));
    resetButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/com/tum4ik/icons/reset.png"));
    solveButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/com/tum4ik/icons/solve.png"));
}
```

When I run application from Intellij Idea all looks good.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnzyD.jpg)

But when I compile application into executable jar file via Build -> Build Artifacts... the icons are not displayed.

Could somebody help me to solve this problem.

Folder structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E11si.jpg)

Comment: Are those files included in the generated jar? Please show the folder structure of your project.

Comment: You need to understand that the loading mechanism must be told that the icons are inside the jar file.

Comment: @Pete Added folder structure.